# Same names in Columns in R

Tags: r

In R, I am using a read_excel function, to import some files, the problem is that my files have some columns with the same name, is there any way to force the same name? (I know it's not a good practice, but it's a very specific thing)

```
New names:
* `44228` -> `44228...4`
* `44229` -> `44229...5`
* `44230` -> `44230...6`
* `44231` -> `44231...7`
* `44232` -> `44232...8`
```

I need to use a conversion factor for these data names, so I need to leave it with the name of the member, they are data.

Comment: as far as I know it is impossible to have columns with the same name. If you give more information about what your initial excel sheet looks like, we can offer a pre-R procedure. Maybe you just have to transpose the data in Excel first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.name_repair` argument of `read_excel()` to control, and turn off, the checks applied to column names by `tibble()`. So to allow duplicate names:

```r
library("readxl")
library("writexl") # Only needed to generate an example xlsx file

x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, a = 1:3, a = 1:3, check.names = FALSE)
write_xlsx(x, "data.xlsx")

read_xlsx("data.xlsx", .name_repair = "minimal")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     a     a
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3
```

Although do be aware that duplicate column names are closer to a syntax error than "bad practice", so the resulting object will behave in strange ways:

```r
df <- read_xlsx("data.xlsx", .name_repair = "minimal")
df$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
```